# Is this AES encrypt safe?

Tags: encryption

Here is my question:

```
two AES key: k1 and k2 use k1 to encrypt k2 generate c and k2 encrypt 
k1 generate d, publish c and d
```

Is this safe? Can any hacker got k1 or k2 from c and d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is safe.  Both `c` and `d` are the result of a key unknown to the attacker being used to encrypt a message that is also unknown to the attacker.  It is as safe as AES is in any other practical scenario.